# Store stdout in variable and send command to background

Tags: bash, shell, background-process, command-substitution

I have a command in a bash script which I want to capture the output of and then send it to the background. How do I get this done?

The following doesn't seem to work (it keeps blocking and outputs nothing)

```
result=`node /var/www/animekyun/node/node_modules/peerflix/app.js $torrent -r -q &`
```

This doesn't seem to work. The output is 2 lines btw which I want to store in a variable as an array. This way I can use the output in the rest of my script.

Comment: basically same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27003331/7552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but this might work with a FIFO:

```
filename=/tmp/my.fifo
mkfifo $filename
node /var/.../app.js $torrent -r -q >$filename &
{ read first_line; read second_line; } <$filename

# do something with "$first_line" and "$second_line"
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want (as I understand it) is impossible. You cannot collect the output (with command substitution) and **then** run the program in the background. for the simple reason that the output is collected over the whole life time of a process. A process may live long after it has stopped producing output but the shell cannot know that.

You have to redirect the output to a file and have to check somehow (that is application-specific) when the output is complete (if you do not want to wait for the process to finish).

```
node /var/www/animekyun/node/node_modules/peerflix/app.js $torrent -r -q >file &
[...]
result="$(<file)"
```

Comment: Correct explanation, but your solution doesn't do anything sensible: it stops reading `file` whenever it feels like it, regardless of the amount of data that's been written to it.

Comment: The text prior to the code mentions that it is up to the user to replace `[...]` with something that determines when it is safe to read from `file`, whether it be calling `wait` to block until the process exits, or waiting until `file` has some minimum length, or something else.

Comment: Since the output is just 2 lines, I can try to read the file and check if it has 2 lines. If that's the case I can continue doing my thing